`pairing` function in `py_ecc.bn128` results in `RecursionError`
I'm using the py_ecc.bn128 library to execute pairing, using two points G1 and G2.
The following code is copied from a tutorial:
from py_ecc.bn128 import G1, G2, pairing, multiply

A = multiply(G2, 5)
B = multiply(G1, 6)
print(pairing(A, B))

The multiply function is working as expected, and I also experimented with adding points, etc.
However, the pairing function keeps throwing the following error:
RecursionError:
maximum recursion depth exceeded

I followed this answer from stackoverflow and set sys.setrecursionlimit(big_number) before importing the library, but the function is still failing with the same error.
FYI: I'm using python@3.12.0 and py_ecc@7.0.1

It seems to be a version incompatibility issue. I switched to python@3.10 and it's working fine now.
